# Why are my grayscale images not being displayed properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, tensorflow2.0, grayscale

I am trying to load grayscale images from the DDSM database and train my Tensorflow model with those images. But when I try to load the images using the `flow_from_directory` function of tensorflow and pass that data to a function that shows the batch it does not get displayed properly.

**Global variables**

```
#variables  
BATCH_SIZE = 25
IMG_HEIGHT = 350
IMG_WIDTH = 350
trainDir = "./data/pictures/"
```

**Show Batch Code**

```
def show_batch(image_batch, label_batch):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

    # Show every picture in batch
    for n in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        ax = plt.subplot(5,5, n+1) 
        #Squeeze from [350, 350, 1] to [350, 350]
        arr = nmp.asarray(nmp.squeeze(image_batch[n]))

        plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1)
        # Find the correct class
        plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[label_batch[n] == 1][0].title())
        plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

**Code**

```
# my image data generator and normalize (0 to 1)
train_generator = 
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Definin the path to my training data (grayscale images)
traindir = pathlib.Path(trainDir)

# Here I am counting the amount of training images (around 500)
train_count = len(list(traindir.glob('*/*.png')))

# getting all the class names (cancer, benign, normal) from the directory
CLASS_NAMES = nmp.array([item.name for item in traindir.glob('*')])

#The flow_from_directory function
train_data_gen = train_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory = str(traindir),
    batch_size= BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,
    color_mode='grayscale', # Grayscale mode
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    classes=list(CLASS_NAMES)
) 

sample_train_images, lbl = next(train_data_gen)
# Here I call the function to show the images.
show_batch(sample_train_images, lbl)
```

So when I run above code I do get an display but the grayscale images are not being displayed properly. I've searched a lot online and tried many things but I cannot fix it.

**My current wrong output**

[image: The output from show_batch.]

**This is how a picture should look like**
[image: Grayscale image that I need to see (in a batch)]

I am worried that due to that I don't see the grayscale image clearly that the model is not going to be trained well.

**Edit 1**
I tried multiplying my array by 255, this didn't change the output. I am maybe thinking the flow_from_directory is not working well.

Answer (score 0):

You have rescaled the images in `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`, in your `show_batch` function multiply your image by 255.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Should I multiply ``image_batch[n] * 255 ``

Comment: Yes, multiply by 255.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But where should I multiply?  arr = nmp.asarray(nmp.squeeze(image_batch[n])) Should this be multiplied?

Comment: Sadly, this does not change the result. It is still the same

Comment: Trying plotting only the first image of the batch. Get rid of subplot and everything, then tell what is the result?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/ZQFSoyP This is the output now. it's still kind of the same.